# Npm doing nothing - no errors, no output

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, ubuntu-20.04

I'm having a problem with `npm` on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I try to check its version (I've just installed it with `sudo apt install npm`, I have NodeJS version 10.19.0) and I don't get any output, just immediately next line in terminal:

[image]

Same thing happens when I try to install something, for instance json-server with `npm install json-server -g`. I don't get any output at all, nothing happens.

It may be that json-server is already installed, because I don't get any error when I'm trying to use it. However, when I try to write `json-server --watch someFile.json`, still nothing happens, there is no hosting of this json file.

What may be the reason of this problem?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot? Are you sure you aren't in some REPL (read-eval-print-loop)?

Comment: Screen added. Simply writing npm -v or just npm produces no output. No error, no success.

Comment: What if you add --loglevel verbose ( `npm -v --loglevel verbose` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing with nvm solved the problem.

Comment: Looks ok, but could you please add what exactly was the problem and that got solved by using node version management?